# Laravel Excel::Import using google cloud storage suddenly stopped working, gives error: mkdir(): No such file or directory

Tags: excel, laravel, import, google-cloud-storage

I've been using Laravel to import files uploaded to google cloud storage for a while.
Without changing any code, the following call suddenly stopped working.

```
Excel::import($importer, $document->path, env('GOOGLE_STORAGE_DISK', 'local'), $fileType);
```

The return error traced from the import method is below.

```
"message": "mkdir(): No such file or directory",
    "exception": "ErrorException",
    "file": "/workspace/vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/Files/TemporaryFileFactory.php",
    "line": 52,
    "trace": [
        {
            "function": "handleError",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/workspace/vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/Files/TemporaryFileFactory.php",
            "line": 52,
            "function": "mkdir"
        },
        {
            "file": "/workspace/vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/Reader.php",
            "line": 398,
            "function": "makeLocal",
            "class": "Maatwebsite\\Excel\\Files\\TemporaryFileFactory",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/workspace/vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/Reader.php",
            "line": 99,
            "function": "getReader",
            "class": "Maatwebsite\\Excel\\Reader",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/workspace/vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/Excel.php",
            "line": 146,
            "function": "read",
            "class": "Maatwebsite\\Excel\\Reader",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php",
            "line": 261,
            "function": "import",
            "class": "Maatwebsite\\Excel\\Excel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/workspace/app/Http/Controllers/ImportController.php",
            "line": 175,
            "function": "__callStatic",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade",
            "type": "::"
        },
```

This is the line that throws the error in TemporaryFileFactory.php

```
if (!file_exists($this->temporaryPath) && !mkdir($concurrentDirectory = $this->temporaryPath) && !is_dir($concurrentDirectory)) {
```

I have no idea at all how to even begin to address this. Since I haven't made any code changes I can only assume a new version of some library is the culprit. However I have tried hard-coding the old library version in my composer.json

```
"maatwebsite/excel": "3.1.19",
```

and running composer install and it seems to make no difference. Any lead at all on what direction to go to try to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: If there haven't been any changes done in your code, I would suggest you reach out to the [developer community on Github](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues) regarding this issue as they would be better suited for answering your questions and concerns related to the library in question.

Answer (score -1):

I decided to use '/tmp' instead,
to do so, I needed to publish and change the config/excel.php

```
php artisan vendor:publish –provider="Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider"
```

edit config/excel.php

```
'local_path'          => '/tmp',
```